# react-native-geocoding@0.4.0 still working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I started working in a legacy code and we use react-native-geocoding@0.4.0 and react-native0.62.2 there, but suddenly it stopped work without apparent reasons.

I tried adding some permissions to AndroidManifest (tried only in Android yet) and didn't worked :(

Does anyone know if it's still working?